# Sitecore 9.0.1 installation stalls during step 10

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation

I'm getting blocked during step 10 when trying to install a Sitecore 9.0.1 instance locally. I'm using the so famous PowerShell script, by the way.

The last few messages I see on the PowerShell prompt are:

```
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'.: Completed.
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'. (Complete)
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'.: Pending.
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'.: Running.
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'. (Start)
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'.: Completed.
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'. (Complete)
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'.: Pending.
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'.: Running.
Info: Enabling index 'ndxUnique'. (Start)
```

Curiously enough only the **Core** database is created so far.

When I open the log file that's what I see at his end:

```
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="XConnect Collection",Value=https://Sitecore901.xconnect
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Xdb Reference Data Client",Value=https://Sitecore901.xconnect
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="XDB MA Reporting Client",Value=https://Sitecore901.xconnect
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="XDB MA Ops Client",Value=https://Sitecore901.xconnect
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="XConnect Server Certificate Validation Thumbprint",Value=32E0174B857D05B0F761B9F9B98FE3AD1AAAF3E3
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="SOLR Connection String",Value=https://solr:8984/solr
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr Core Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_core_index
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr Master Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_master_index
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr Web Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_web_index
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr Marketing Definitions Master Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_marketingdefinitions_master
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr Marketing Definitions Web Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_marketingdefinitions_web
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr Marketing Asset Master Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_marketing_asset_index_master
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr Marketing Asset Web Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_marketing_asset_index_web
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr Testing Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_testing_index
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr Suggested Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_suggested_test_index
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr FXM Master Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_fxm_master_index
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Solr FXM Web Index Name",Value=Sitecore901_fxm_web_index
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="Telerik Encryption Key",Value=PutYourCustomEncryptionKeyHereFrom32To256CharactersLong
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="EXM EDS Provider",Value=CustomSMTP
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="EXM Cryptographic Key",Value=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
VERBOSE: [WebDeploy]:[Arg] -SetParam:Name="EXM Authentication Key",Value=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
```

Comment: Can you please specific about what issues you are facing with the installation?

Comment: The installation simply gets stalled and nothing happens. I've been waiting for something for more than 40 minutes and still nothing.

Comment: Which SQL are you using? Does the core database have any tables?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 13.2.5026.0 and only the website **Core** database was created at that time.

Comment: I am sure there is a good reason you are installing 9.0.1, but SIF 2.0 was a much better experience for me to use than earlier versions, can you use 9.1?

Comment: Actually, I’m using them all. The reason I’m installing all those versions is because I’m mounting a test environment to qualify/validate our Sitecore module :)